# Android SoundPool play sound over bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, soundpool

```
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

(load file to soundPool)

soundPool.play(soundId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1f);
```

but I want that file is played in bluetooth headset. The problem is that is always played in telephone speaker.

Is it possible that file is palyed on bluetooth headset when I am using SoundPool?

Comment: Maybe you should try AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL.

Comment: it is the same. i already tried

Comment: any luck with that?